# Defining a Model Accessor with a DB query

Tags: php, laravel

I'm attempting to set an attribute on a model where you do something like:

```
public function getLatestLeadAttribute()
{
    return $this->leads()->latest()->first();
}
```

However I'm receiving an error when I try:

```
public function getLatestLeadAttribute()
{
    $lead = $this->leads()->latest()->first();

    return $lead->created_at; // Returning 'Cannot get property of non- object';
}
```

But if I do the following:

```
public function getLatestLeadAttribute()
{
    $lead = $this->leads()->latest()->first();

    dd($lead); // Returns App/Lead instance

    return $lead->created_at;
}
```

It returns the lead instance as expected and even if I `dd($lead->created_at)` I receive the carbon object I'm looking for.

Any particular reason why It's not letting me return the created_at time of the latest Model created?

Comment: Do you access `->latestLead` multiple times in your code?

Comment: No, I've built most of my application using VueJS so I'm just expecting it to show up when I call the parent. If I just call `return $this->leads()->latest()->first();` I get the model, I do not want the entire model as I don't want the user to see it. I just want to return the date it was created at.

Comment: "Cannot get property of non- object" means that the model doesn't have a `lead`. Did you test `dd()` with the same model?

Comment: I feel extremely stupid, just having one of those days. Yeah I was doing a get query on all events and not all events have a lead hence the issue. Why is why when I was running `dd()` I was getting the model. Edit: Thank you for the second set of eyes.

Comment: `dd()` ends the execution when you use it. So apparently, the first model had a `lead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code always has the potential to create a problem for models that don't have a related lead.  You could simplify your code and get rid of that problem by just querying for the created_at value instead of trying to rely on the entire lead model:

```
public function getLatestLeadAttribute()
{
    return $this->leads()->latest()->value('created_at');
}
```

This will only select the latest created_at in related leads, or return null if no related leads exist.  This not only will fix the access error but be more efficient than retrieving all of the fields from the database.

Comment: I needed literally the last `lead` related to a parent, so wouldn't it be `return $this->leads()->latest()->value('created_at')->first();`?

Comment: No.  `value('created_at')` essentially does a `SELECT created_at ... LIMIT 1` and returns the value of created_at.  You'd be calling first on the carbon object.